# Order of the two elements

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let S denote the group of all those permutations of the English alphabet that fix the letters T,E,N,D,U,L,K,A and R. Other letters may or may not be fixed. Show that S has elements σ, τ of order 36 and 39 respectively, but does not have any element of order 37 or 38.
I know that order of a element in Sn is the l.c.m of the orders of disjoint cycles now any element will have the identity permutation of order 1 and the remaining ones then order is of the form 9 and something with 9 as l.c.m is this approach right

Please help!!

Comment: The identity permutation has order $1$, not $9$.

Comment: Yes it has order 1 but if we break into disjoint cycles then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

|Alphabet|-|excluded letters| $= 26 - 9=17$.
So we are working in $S_{17}$.
An element is in $S_{17}$ iff the sum of the lengths of its disjoint cycles is $\le 17$.
Order $36$ is composed of disjoint cycles of length $9 \text { and } 4 \;$ sum = 13.
Order $39$ is composed of disjoint cycles of length $13 \text { and } 3 \;$ sum = 16.
Order $38$ is composed of disjoint cycles of length $19 \text { and } 2 \;$ sum = 21.
Order $37$ is composed of one disjoint cycle of length $37$

Comment: I a had the same argument thanks anyway